# Accessing extended functionality from Java classloaded classes

Tags: java, classloader, extend

I have a class (Class A) that extends another class (Class B). I classload Class A dynamically and I wish to access the extended functionalities via Class A.

Example:

```
Class A extends Class B
- function getName()

Class B
- function abstract getName()
- function doSomethingElse()
```

How do I do it in Java (accessing doSomethingElse()) ?

---

I was reading through the codes and I suspected this might be the line of code:

```
public Object invoke(String classname, String method, Object args) {
        Object res = null;
        try {
            for (Class i : classes) {
                if (i.getName().equals(classname)) {
                    Object obj = i.newInstance();
                    Method loadMethod = i.getMethod(method, null);
                    res = loadMethod.invoke(obj, args);
                }
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I am trying to write an adapter for the method.invoke() method to make it easier for methods to be called but the errors all pointed to this code fragment producing all the problems. I set my getMethod's 2nd argument to null and I think that's the problem but I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are asking how to use reflection. It is useful to notice that `getName()` already exists on the `java.lang.Class`.

If a class includes abstract methods, the class itself must be declared abstract:

```
package com.sandbox;

abstract public class B {
    public abstract String getName();
    public String doSomethingElse() {
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Next, define the extending class.

```
package com.sandbox;

public class A extends B {
    public String getName() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

Finally, for a sloppy example of reflection usage:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Program {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InstantiationException 
     * @throws InvocationTargetException 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {

        // use a class loader to dynamically load a class
        ClassLoader classLoader = Program.class.getClassLoader();
        Class<?> aClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.sandbox.A");

        // all methods defined on the class and its superclasses and superinterfaces are available through getMethods() call
        Method[] allMethods = aClass.getMethods();
        for (Method m : allMethods) {
            if (m.getName() == "doSomethingElse") {
                String result = (String) m.invoke(aClass.newInstance(), null);
                System.out.println("Function call is " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that should output

> Function call is done

Comment: I do have a method that does the above but it dumps at me a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: @thotheolh Could you share your code then? We might find the error easier.

Comment: The codes are very bulky and complex. I have posted a fragment that I think is causing the problem below.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Especially for moving the replies for me. I figured that the problem was due to parameter types. E.g. you have doSomethingElse(Socket sock) in Class B and you have an Object of a Socket class, invoke("doSomethingElse", (Object) socket), it wouldn't work because you need both the invoke params type to match exactly.